# EditText border color on threesides only with shape.xml

Tags: android, xml, android-edittext

Hi I want the edittext border colour only on left,top and right with blue colour but bottom should be transparent or grey.

How can I achieve this using shape.xml

As of now I am using the below code but unable to make the bottom line grey

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:thickness="0dp"
android:shape="rectangle"
>
<stroke android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#49b1bb"
        />

<corners android:radius="0dp" />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code will help you to achieve your goal:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <!-- Border -->
    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#49b1bb" >
            </solid>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <!-- Body -->
    <item
        android:left="2dip"
        android:right="2dp"
        android:top="2dp">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#ffafafaf" >
            </solid>
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

What exactly above code is doing is it simply create border for all side first then after that It is adding layer on bottom border so that it is not visible to user.

Happy coding!!!!!!!!!!